# Wordpress single post content class customization with if-else function

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code, which displays the content for my custom page template "*landingpage.php*" and for single posts. The site uses Bootstrap 4.

```
<?php if(is_page_template( 'landingpage.php' )): ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

        <?php elseif (is_single()): ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content pt-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

        <?php else: ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a more elegant and/or shorter way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third `<div>` appears to be the same in all three cases, so that can be abstracted out of the cases.

The outermost `<div>` appears to have class `pt-4` applied only if `is_page_template( 'landingpage.php' )` returns a value that evaluates to `FALSE` *and* `is_single()` returns a value that evaluates to `TRUE`.

And the first nested (i.e. second) `<div>` has class `container-fluid` if either of those functions return a value that evaluates to `TRUE`.

This logic could be rewritten as below. I know it strays away from the familiar wordpress style of using the [Alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and uses the *shortcut syntax* (i.e. `<?=`) of `echo` but it does add some separation of the logic from the markup

```
<?php
// default class names
$contentClass = 'site-content';
$containerClass = 'container-fluid';
if (!is_page_template( 'landingpage.php' )) {
    if (is_single()) {
        $contentClass .= ' pt-4';
    }
    else {
        $containerClass = 'container';
    }
}
?>
    <div id="content" class="<?= $contentClass; ?>">
        <div class="<?= $containerClass; ?>">
            <div class="row">
```

It could be simplified using [ternary operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) but some may argue that would detract from readability.

- *Is this shorter*?

  yes, only by two lines
- *is this more elegant*?

  Well, that is subjective. The code above should be simpler to read. Consider the scenario where the code is updated by multiple people, including programmers and designers. The programmers can have designers update the markup without affecting the business logic. For more on this topic, refer to [Mixing PHP and HTML](https://thisinterestsme.com/mixing-php-html/).

Comment: In php, `if`, `elseif`, and `else` are [language constructs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).  I assume languages like javascript do not have `elseif` which would explain why they require a space to form `else if`.  When writing php, please suggest the use of the single language construct `elseif`, versus using two language constructs `else` (an else branch with no curly bracing) followed immediately by a new `if` branch.

Comment: Updated- you are correct about [JS not having `elseif`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Examples) - and there are interesting comments on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4005623/1575353)

Comment: Maybe I should have added these links as well to help explain to researchers... https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php  and 
 https://www.amitmerchant.com/difference-between-elseif-and-else-if-php/

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you so much for the improvement, that's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: No worries- thank you for taking the time to accept the answer. Please consider voting on it as well. ["_The first thing you should do after reading someone's answer to your question is vote on the answer, like any user with sufficient reputation does. Vote up answers that are helpful, and vote down answers that give poor advice._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)